# Кроссбраузерная автоматическая печать изображения

Tags: javascript, печать, кроссбраузерность

Задача: сделать на сайте так, чтобы графический файл автоматически отправлялся на принтер. Сама печать легко запускается через `window.print()`, но при этом распечатанный результат получается разного размера из разных браузеров: из IE печатается, как и задумано, на весь лист А4, из Firefox картинка занимает меньше четверти листа, из Opera и Chrome — нечто среднее. Пробовал устанавливать размер картинки через CSS, указывая в качестве единицы измерения дюймы (in) — не помогает.

Как сделать, чтобы рисунок печатался на полный лист из любого браузера?

**UPD:** Решил проблему, установив для рисунка width:100% через css media=print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузеры практически не дают управлять параметрами печати.
Для Опреы и Хрома можно указать отступы в CSS:

```
@media print{
  @page: {margin: 0%}
}
```

Остальные браузеры это игнорируют, подставляют значения, указываемые пользователем (или по дефолту). То же касается колонтитулов - полностью пользовательская настройка.
А так печать картинки при выставленных одинаковых параметрах отступов, колонтитулов и галки "по ширине страницы" печатается одинаково.

Устанавливайте картинке `width:100%` в правилах для `@media print`, дальнейшее будет зависеть от пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: переопределить css картинки через [[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) print{}](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media).
Вариант 2: перед печатью установить нужные настройки печати. Но этим будет заниматься пользователь - все-таки, принтер его.

Answer (score 1):

Специально для вас подумал и вот что придумал:

```
function atoprint(src) {
    var atext = '<img src="' + src + '">';
    var captext = window.document.title;
    var alink = window.document.location;
    var prwin = open('');
    //prwin.document.open();
    prwin.document.writeln(htmls.text3);
    prwin.document.writeln('<h1>'+captext+'<\/h1>');
    prwin.document.writeln('<div style="position: absolute; height: 600px; top: 150px; width: 700px;">'+atext+'<\/div>');
    prwin.document.writeln('<hr><div style="font-size:8pt;margin-top:20px;">© site.ru<\/div>');
    prwin.document.writeln('<div style="font-size:8pt;">Страница материала: '+alink+'<\/div>');
    prwin.document.writeln('<\/div><\/body><\/html>');
    prwin.print();
    prwin.close;
};
```

передаете только `src` ну и в разметке что у меня есть тоже можете что нибудь поправить!